# Logging out using devise - I'm getting the right routes but it's not logging out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to rails and trying to incorporate Devise to handle user sessions. I want the user to log out, and it is hitting the right route but the session is not deleted and the user is still logged in. Need help please!

The link in the view is:

```
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

The Server log is:

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Cyapc8vOXq1FmDZYxrJFPiZFfj77y0aScieiAbMWBxFcoHB3Pr4gvsihf5AQK4VbH8QV24j8IMSpJqnAWEitPQ=="}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =
?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]] Redirected to
http://localhost:3000/ Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your /app/assets/javascripts/application.js file, have you this lines ?

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

The second line is important for delete methode

Comment: Since he has hit the correct controller action, it's already in place. Otherwise he'd get a routing error about using `GET` instead of `DELETE`.

Comment: hi there, thanks for the advice. The lines are there in the application.js already though.

Answer (score 0):

Check if **current_user** returns *true* or *false*.

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %> or
  <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment - it looks like it still returns true.